# Redhat Fuse and PAM usecases

Tags: microservices, redhat, jbossfuse, pam, fuseesb

I am starting to build a new application on microservices/API-driven architecture. I do have some requirements for business process management (Human approval activity) and straight-through processing.

Can I use Redhat PAM alone for BPM as well as a microservices orchestration use case or is it recommended to use Fuse with it? I am confused with the usage of Fuse. What are the common use cases of Fuse and PAM?

Is Red Hat PAM can also do microservices orchestration. Do you think it is a viable solution choice for this use-case? Please guide.

Regards
Vinay

Answer (score 0):

if I had to do this I would use something like the api-provider (https://github.com/syndesisio/syndesis-quickstarts/tree/trunk/api-provider) of FuseOnline/Syndesis and have RH PAM call into these endpoints. So in essence RH PAM becomes the orchestrator. Does that help you?
--Kurt